# Unable to write pdf on android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I am using following code to create a pdf file, but after executing the code file is not being created on the physical location of device.

```
tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";     
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());   
File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
prepareDirectory();      
String uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();    

String current = uniqueId + ".pdf";       
File  mypath= new File(directory,current);    
System.out.println(".....................1");
try {
    mypath.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
Document document = new Document();  
System.out.println(".....................2");
try {
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(mypath));
    System.out.println(".....................3");

    document.open();

    System.out.println(".....................4");
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    preface.add(new Paragraph("First Paragraph"));
    document.add(preface);
    System.out.println(".....................5");


    document.add(chap);
    document.close();
    System.out.println(".....................6");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(".................inside filenotfound exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (DocumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    System.out.println(".................inside document exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Show your log cat messages..

Comment: 11-26 15:03:12.642: E/dalvikvm(27435): Could not find class 'com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPrinterGraphics2D', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.createPrinterGraphics

Comment: 11-26 15:03:12.682: I/dalvikvm(27435): Could not find method java.awt.geom.AffineTransform.getMatrix, referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setTextMatrix

Comment: Are you using the desktop version of iText, or the Android port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PdfPrinterGraphics2D` class is part of iText (for Java), but not part of iTextG (for Android / GAE). If you get a *could not find class* exception, you're using the wrong iText. You should use the Android port: http://itextpdf.com/product/itextg